# Help with finding the $\lim_{x\to 0} \tan x \csc (2x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

So I am trying to figure out the limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \tan x  \csc (2x)$$

I am not sure what action needs to be done to solve this and would appreciate any help to solving this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We have $\csc(2x)=\frac{1}{\sin(2x)}$ and $\sin(2x)=2\sin x\cos x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\csc (2x) = \frac{1}{\sin(2x)} = \frac{1}{2 \sin x \cos x}$, and $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$.

So $$\lim_{x \to 0} \tan x \csc (2x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{2 \sin x \cos x} \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{2 \cos^2 x} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \tan x \csc (2x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \frac{1}{\sin 2x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \frac{1}{2\sin x\cos x}$$

Can you take from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\csc{2x} = \frac{1}{\sin 2x} = \frac{1}{2 \sin x \cos x}
$$
Then 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \frac{ 1}{2 \sin x \cos x}= 
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2 \cos^2 x} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score -1):

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \tan x  \csc (2x)= \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{2\cos^2x\sin x} = 1/2
$$